# fill a picker usin json according to a condition

Tags: react-native, if-statement, picker

I can fill a picker using json stocked in state

```
  produits: [{
      "code": 11,
      "pu": 50,
      "ps": 50,
      "des": "P 1",
      "promo": "1",
    }, {
      "code": 22,
      "pu": 100,
      "ps": 100,
      "des": "P 2",
      "promo": "1",
    }, {
      "code": 33,
      "pu": 80,
      "ps": 80,
      "des": "P 3",
      "promo": "0",
    },
    {
      "code": 44,
      "pu": 120,
      "ps": 120,
      "des": "P 4",
      "promo": "1",
    },
  ],
```

what I want is the same thing but if produits.promo === '1' this item will be shown else it will not be shown, this is my approach but it  have an empty picker: whene I click nothing changes :

```
          {<Picker
            style={Styles.picker}
            selectedValue={this.state.pu}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({pu: itemValue, codeProduit: itemIndex+1,})} >
            { this.state.produits.map((item, key)=>
              {if (item.promo === "0") {
                <Picker.Item label={item.des} value={item.pu} key={item.code} />
                }
              }
            )}
          </Picker>}
```

PS. it works good without `If` block:

```
<Picker.Item label={item.des} value={item.pu} key={item.code} />
```

what's wrong with my approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a new produits array using the filter

```
render() {
const promoProduits = this.state.produits.filter(item => item.promo === '1');
....
```

Then render like

```
{<Picker
    style={Styles.picker}
    selectedValue={this.state.pu}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({pu: itemValue, codeProduit: itemIndex+1,})} >
    {
     promoProduits.map((item, key)=> (<Picker.Item label={item.des} value={item.pu} key={item.code} />)
    }
</Picker>}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got you right, but I'll give it a try. For explanation, see code comments.

**render Method**:

```
 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Picker
            selectedValue={this.state.pu}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({pu: itemValue, codeProduit: itemIndex+1,})} >
            {this.renderPicker()}            
          </Picker>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

**renderPicker Method:**

```
  renderPicker(){
    const items = this.state.produits.map((item, key)=> {
      // if item.promo === "1" return picker item 
      if (item.promo === "1") {
      // make sure to return Picker Item
      return (<Picker.Item label={item.des} value={item.pu} key={item.code} />);
      }
    });
    // return list of pickers
    return items; 
  }
```

**Output:**

[image: Output:]

**Working Example:**

https://snack.expo.io/@tim1717/trembling-turkish-delight